# Access derived class' functions through pointer (C++)

Tags: c++

Here's an example of the situation:

```
CAnimal *poTest = new CDog();
```

When I write "poTest->" All I can see are functions from the base class (in example: CAnimal) and not the ones in the derived one. How can I access these?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've declared **poTest** as a **CAnimal**.

So it makes sense that you'll only see what a **CAnimal** can see.

If you want to use methods that a **CDog** uses, declare it so.

Answer (score 2):

```
CDog * test = new CDog();
test->someFunction();


CAnimal *poTest = new CDog();
static_cast<CDog *>(poTest)->someFunction();
```

I'm assuming `CDog` (what's with the C prefix btw) inherits `CAnimal`. The compiler cannot know that your `poTest` variable happens to be a `CDog` - it can only see that it is a `CAnimal`. So, you can't call a member function of `CDog` with a variable of type `CAnimal *` - you need to convert the pointer to a `CDog *`, this tells the compiler to "treat this as a CDog".

Comment: I agree with this solution, but If you don't use this casting too many times during your program run, it is more robust to use dynamic_cast<CDOG *> and make sure the return value isn't null.

Comment: You should add a caveat about `static_cast` and virtual base classes (i.e., that the results are undefined).

Answer (score 1):

In general in such a case you should only be using the interface of the base class and that function wouldn't be accessible. If you're trying to use the derived interface, consider storing a pointer to `CDog` instead of `CAnimal`. Instead of trying to get to the child methods, make your parent interface appropriate.

If you really know that your pointer points to a dog you can downcast although this may be a design smell in some cases:

```
CDog* cdog = dynamic_cast<CDog *>(poTest);  // Safer
if(cdog)
{
    cdog->someFunction();
}

static_cast<CDog *>(poTest)->someFunction();   // Faster
```

Answer (score 0):

Either define it as a dog:

```
 CDog *poTest = new CDog();
```

Or use a cast:

```
static_cast<CDog*>(poTest)->bark();
```

Or, as per some of the other answers use [one of the other casting functions/operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5f6c9f8h%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). In general, however, making heavy use of casts is considered bad practice; this is one of the reasons why many mainstream languages offer generics (see e.g., [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x6a29h6.aspx)).

Comment: Using C-Style cast is not guaranteed to work. This is approximately equivalent to reinterpret_cast<CDog*>()

Comment: @Martin: I've updated the answer to present `static_cast` as the 'base case.'

Answer (score 0):

Since you declare poTest being an CAnimal, you can just call functions defined in CAnimal. Usually this is enougth since the base class should expose the method needed as virtual functions, dealing with a CAnimal instance and having to cast a CDog usually signal that there is something to improve in the design.

Answer (score 0):

```
dynamic_cast<CDog*>(poTest)->CDogSpecificFunction();
```

Comment: Why use `dynamic_cast` if you aren't going to check the result?

Comment: @James McNellis : Because the results of `static_cast` would be undefined if `CAnimal` is a virtual base of `CDog`. If `CAnimal` is a non-virtual base, I would of course use `static_cast`, but the OP did not give actual class definitions so this seems more prudent.

Comment: It's only more prudent if you check the result. If it is wrong you are de-referencing a NULL pointer. Alternatively using a reference will generate a std::bad_cast: `dynamic_cast<CDog&>(*poTest).CDogSpecificFunction();`

Comment: @Martin: In general, very much agreed; for the code the OP posted, where it is 100% known that the pointer points to a `CDog` instance, /shrug.

Comment: @Martin : Nope, §5.2.9/8 says otherwise. If `CAnimal` is a virtual base of `CDog`, then even if you 100% know that it points at a `CDog` instance you **must** use `dynamic_cast`, as using `static_cast` would yield undefined behavior.

Comment: @ildjarn: §5.2.9/8 Talks about casting away const-ness in my version of the standard (n3092). **But you are correct**; I missed the part about `virtual base` in your comment.

Comment: @Martin : §5.2.9/8 is the C++03 citation; the current C++0x draft (n3242) citation is §5.2.9/11. :-]